# Why does HTML5 checkValidity() return different results from JavaScript regexp.test()?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, checkvalidity

In JS, I can run:

```
/[a-z]/.test('foo');
```

Which returns `true`, as a single lowercase character appears anywhere inside the string.

However:

```
<input pattern="[a-z]" value="foo" required />
```

and

```
console.log(document.querySelector('input').checkValidity())
```

Returns `false`.

**Why does HTML5 checkValidity return different results from JavaScript regexp.test()** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset.

— https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

So `pattern="[a-z]"` is equivalent to `/^[a-z]$/.test('foo');`